# How can I create a time control using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, timer

I would like to create a time control as it exists in "Date and Time Settings" on Windows using VB.NET.

I mean this one control:

[image]

But I don't want to have "πμ" appearing. 
How can I erase "πμ" (which holds for "pm" in my language)?

Comment: That control is three textboxes (contain time components), two labels (contain ":") and an [updown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759880.aspx).

Comment: Then you already have [`MaskedEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). Hack it togever with [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown).

Comment: The problem is that numericUpdown has its own textbox

Comment: I can't understand. How the textbox of NumericUpdown can be overriden by the maskedit?

Comment: [Magically](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBAFV.png).

Comment: Why are concerned with Microsofts Patents? They are to protect MSFT's intellectual property against competitors (like apple, google and oracle). Microsoft know they cant do/provide everything and  encourage people to make user controls like this Date Time control you wish to create.

Comment: @GSerg: I don't like your "hack"

Comment: @JeremyThompson Well, I was trying to be helpful, for which it was required to accept the fact the control needs to be created. Otherwise I would have to vote for close, because the real question is seeking a legal advice, not a programming advice. The programming advice would also be not exactly ingenious (put a [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) on the form, set `ShowUpDown` to `true` and `Format` to `Time`).

Comment: @JeremyThompson: I want to sell this program that's why I asked if it is patented.

Answer (score 0):

As GSerg stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254554/how-can-i-create-a-time-control-using-vb-net/11264940#comment14792927_11254554):

Use a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) control. Set the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format.aspx) property to "Custom", the [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property to "HH:mm:ss", ShowUpDown to true.

You can't directly pass a TimeSpan in to a DateTimePicker, but you can set it's value to 
`someDateAtMidnight.Add(myTimeSpan)`

Comment: thanks it seems ok but I would like to ask if it is possible to pass in it the value of a Timespan in text format.

Comment: why DateTimePicker2.Value.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. But it sounds like if the DateTimePicker is a suitable control as you asked in your question, you should consider posting a separate question about handling dates and timespans.